# Show list content from different site collection on a modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages

Is there any available webparts or easy way to display List content from different site collection on a Modern page?

I know, we can build SPFx webpart, looking for any other options.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Highlighted content web part on Modern Team sites or groups to dynamically display content from a document library, a site, a site collection, or all sites.

Reference:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-highlighted-content-web-part-e34199b0-ff1a-47fb-8f4d-dbcaed329efd?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Comment: Thanks for bringing it up. Looked into it and will keep this option handy. In my case, I need to display content from a List. Looking for some thing like Content Query webpart, with control to style or at least with selected fields(views) .